# Pug (Jade) templating engine is malforming my string

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

If I create a test function on my backend such as :

```
function testFunction(){

  return 'https://test.com/?test=erhc0m24t0v&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fbienestar'

}
```

Then I pass it to the view when it is rendered, and from within the view I call:

```
script.
      console.log('#{testFunction()}')
```

It wrecks my string by adding what I believe is a url encoded space and a semicolon:

`https://test.com/?test=erhc0m24t0v&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fbienestar`

Whereas expected output is simply:

`https://test.com/?test=erhc0m24t0v&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fbienestar`

What is causing this to happen? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *escaped* string interpolation `#{`
Try using the *unescaped* string interpolation `!{`

Source: [Pug's interpolation reference](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html)

Comment: Thanks man would have never guessed, appreciate it.